# 3ds max script make group by parents

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

Hy!
I am not so well experienced with max script, but I have written/modified an exporter that can export single meshes, groups using the built in obj exporter.

Now I want to select parents(usually theese are not 3Dobjects) in hierarchy and convert them to groups with their parrents, and I have no idea how exatly I should do it.
Any suggestions maybe script code you know?

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the parent of any object in the scene by using

```
myParent = $myObject.parent
```

And you can use the following line to get all of a parent's children:

```
myParent.children
```

so in combination with select and group methods, you can do the following:

```
myParent = $myObject.parent
select myParent
selectmore myParent.children
group (GetCurrentSelection() as array) name:"myGroup"
```

And now you have a group named myGroup containing a parent object and all of its children. With a little tinkering you can turn this into a method and also iterate through every object in your scene. Hope this helps you.

Comment: I will try that and will mark it as a good answer, max scripts don't have so good manual.